# SwiftUI: How to pass a data from one view and use it in the viewModel of another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Just playing around with passing data between views and using it in view models. Below is the code for the FirstView from which to pass a phone number:

```
struct FirstView: View {

    @State private var phone: String = "9876543210"
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.background
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                TextField("type here...", text: $phone)
                   .onTapGesture {
                              isPresented.toggle()
                         }
                   .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                            SecondView(phone: phone)
                        })
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I use the phone data passed from main view in sub view model as the initial value for the textfield? Below is the unfinished code for SecondView:

```
struct SecondView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = SecondViewModel()
    let phone: String // how to assign this obtained data in viewModel.phone?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.background
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                // textfield default text should be the phone number passed from FirstView
                TextField("type here...", text: $viewModel.phone)  
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the second view model:

```
final class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var phone = ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `init` and `StateObject(wrappedValue:)`. Here is the possible solution.

Your view model

```
final class SubViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var phone = ""
    
    init(phone: String) {
        self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

Your subview

```
struct SubView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel: SubViewModel
    private let phone: String
    
    init(phone: String) {
        self.phone = phone
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: SubViewModel(phone: phone))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.background
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                // textfield default text should be the phone number passed from main view
                TextField("type here...", text: $viewModel.phone)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```